# How to publish metrics with aws lambda before lambda exits?

Tags: logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer

I have java 17 lambda implemented as image. I am using micrometer cloudwatch dependency for publishing metrics.

Creating metrics beans as -

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient() {
    return CloudWatchAsyncClient.builder().region(Region.of("us-east-1")).build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public MeterRegistry getMeterRegistry(CloudWatchAsyncClient cloudWatchAsyncClient) {
    CloudWatchConfig cloudWatchConfig = setupCloudWatchConfig();
    return new CloudWatchMeterRegistry(cloudWatchConfig, Clock.SYSTEM, cloudWatchAsyncClient);
}

private CloudWatchConfig setupCloudWatchConfig() {
    return new CloudWatchConfig() {

        private final Map<String, String> configuration =
                Map.of(
                        "cloudwatch.namespace",
                        "serviceName",
                        "cloudwatch.step",
                        Duration.ofSeconds(1).toString());

        @Override
        public String get(String key) {
            return configuration.get(key);
        }
    };
}
```

However if my lambda run for 3.5 seconds, metrics collected in last 0.5 seconds are lost.
I am expecting lambda request execution time to be between 1 to 25 seconds.

How can I force lambda to publish metrics?
I came across meterRegistry.close() method, however if I close meterRegistry, upcoming requests wont have meterRegistry running. I am creating meterRegistry as a singleton bean.

Can someone guide on -

1. how can I force lambda to flush metrics before function invocation ends.